# How MongoDB sorts if sorting field in not existing in most of the documents

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have millions of documents in my collection. By mistake, I have executed sort by field(and limit) command where that field does not exist in any of the documents. In this case, I didn't get an error from MongoDB instead I got some output from it. So could you please let me know how MongoDB handles sorting command wherein field does not exist. Does it loads all the data into memory and search for that field(since the index is present for that field) and return the output based on the _id field.

Answer (score 1):

A non-existing value for a field is assigned a special marker value and will sort either before or after all other values for the field. This is the [same value as a field with a `null` value](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#non-existent-fields) gets. The value of other fields (such as `_id`) does not play a role here.

An index on the field will still be used, as the index also includes all documents that do not have a value for the field (unless you declared this to be a sparse index).